# Active Record join query

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model-associations

I have three models: **Question**, **User** and **Qrecord**. A **Qrecord** stores how many times the **User** has answered the **Question** correctly (in the column :answered) and when it was last answered (in the column :last_answered).

So, a Question has_many Qrecords and a User has_many Qrecords. A Qrecord belongs_to :user and :question.

Qrecord Model

```
id            :integer          not null, primary key
user_id       :integer
question_id   :integer
answered      :integer
last_answered :datetime
```

For an array of questions, how do I return the one in which :last_answered was the longest time ago?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the array of questions is `questions` and the user record `user`:

```
user.qrecords.where(question_id: questions.pluck(:id)).order(:last_answered).last.question
```

Comment: Nearly right. It also needs the user_id for the qrecord. If you edit it to make the where condition where(question_id: questions.pluck(:id), user_id: user)..., I will mark it as correct.

Comment: In that case you can use `user.qrecords.where...`. I updated the answer.

Comment: BTW: Accepting the answer would be very kind.